# How to get a document data angular 6

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular6

I've document id and try to get document data by id:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  customerDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Customer>;
  customer: Observable<Customer>;

    constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { 
      const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');  
      this.customerDoc = afs.collection<Customer>('customers/'+id);
      this.customer = this.customerDoc.snapshotChanges();
  }
}
```

But it's return nothing.

Comment: have you checked if your `id` is null?

Comment: Yes, Id is correct

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
this.afs.collection<Customer>('customers/'+id).snapshotChanges().map(actions=>{
   return actions.map(b=>{
     const data = b.payload.doc.data();
     const id = b.payload.doc.id;
     return {uid:id,...data}
   })
```

});